# how to clear the empty space while image is null?

Tags: android, imageview

I'm new to android domain.

My problem is..
I'm getting a empty space in the image view. From the database im retrieve the image as string and stored in array and displaying. When im getting null in the string that time i should not get a empty white space.

How to clear this? Any one help me..
Thanks a lot in advance...

I try like this...

> ```
>         String pic = imgarr.get(g);
>         System.out.println("picture:"+pic);
>         if (pic != null && !pic.equals("")) {
>             ImageView ImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
>             ImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
>         }else{
>         try {
>               ImageView im = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
>               Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL("http://11.0.0.2/htss/kumar/image/"+pic).getContent());
>               im.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
>             } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
>               e.printStackTrace();
>             } 
>         }
> ```

XML

> ```
>         <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>           xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>             tools:context=".Quesans" >
>         <ScrollView 
> android:layout_width="fill_parent"
> android:layout_height="3500dip"
> android:scrollbars="vertical"
>
>  <RelativeLayout
> android:layout_width="fill_parent"
> android:layout_height="fill_parent">
>  <RadioGroup
>  android:id="@+id/rdgroup"
>  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>  android:layout_below="@+id/que_txt"
>  android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
>  android:orientation="vertical" >
>  <RadioButton android:id="@+id/RB1" android:text=""/>
>  <RadioButton android:id="@+id/RB2" android:text=""/>
>  <RadioButton android:id="@+id/RB3" android:text=""/>
>  <RadioButton android:id="@+id/RB4" android:text=""/>
> </RadioGroup>
> <ImageView
>  android:id="@+id/nxt_btn"
>  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>  android:layout_below="@+id/rdtxt"
>  android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
>  android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
>  android:src="@drawable/next_normal" />
> <TextView
>  android:id="@+id/rdtxt"
>  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>  android:layout_below="@+id/rdgroup"
>  android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
>  android:text="Nothing is picked" 
>  android:textColor="#0000FF"/>
>  <ImageView
>  android:id="@+id/focusarea"
>  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>  android:layout_alignRight="@+id/nxt_btn"
>  android:layout_below="@+id/nxt_btn"
>  android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
>  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>  android:src="@drawable/focus_normal" />
>  <TextView
>  android:id="@+id/que_txt"
>  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>  android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
>  android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
>  android:text="TextView" />
>  <ImageView
>  android:id="@+id/app"
>  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>    android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
>   android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
>  android:src="@drawable/newapps" />
> <ImageView
>  android:id="@+id/image"
>  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>  android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/que_txt"
>  android:layout_below="@+id/que_txt"
>  android:layout_marginTop="150dp" />
> <TextView
>  android:id="@+id/soltxt"
>  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>  android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/prv_btn"
>  android:layout_alignTop="@+id/focusarea"
>  android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
>  android:text="" />
>  <ImageView
>  android:id="@+id/prv_btn"
>  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>  android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image"
>  android:layout_alignTop="@+id/nxt_btn"
>  android:src="@drawable/previous_normal" />
>  </RelativeLayout>
>  </ScrollView>
>  </RelativeLayout>
> ```

Comment: Could you show es the layout you,de using?

Comment: does http://10.0.2.2/moodle/practice/question/images/"+pic shows a empty white space?

Comment: how to check the null link when pic is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
if(imgarr.get(g)!=null)
{
    String pic = imgarr.get(g).toString().trim();
    System.out.println("picture:"+pic);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        if (pic.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
                    imageView .setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else{
                try {
                      Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL("http://10.0.2.2/moodle/practice/question/images/"+pic).getContent());
                      imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                } 
    }
```

**Edited**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".Quesans">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
             android:id="@+id/que_txt"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
             android:text="TextView" />
        <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/image"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/que_txt"
             android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
             android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
             android:layout_below="@+id/que_txt"/>
         <RadioGroup
             android:id="@+id/rdgroup"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_below="@+id/image"
             android:orientation="vertical" >
         <RadioButton 
             android:id="@+id/RB1" 
             android:text=""/>
         <RadioButton 
             android:id="@+id/RB2" 
             android:text=""/>
         <RadioButton 
             android:id="@+id/RB3" 
             android:text=""/>
         <RadioButton 
             android:id="@+id/RB4" 
             android:text=""/>
        </RadioGroup>
        <TextView
             android:id="@+id/rdtxt"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_below="@+id/rdgroup"
             android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
             android:text="Nothing is picked" 
             android:textColor="#0000FF"/>
        <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/nxt_btn"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_below="@+id/rdtxt"
             android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
             android:src="@drawable/next_normal" />
         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/focusarea"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignRight="@+id/nxt_btn"
             android:layout_below="@+id/nxt_btn"
             android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
             android:src="@drawable/focus_normal" />
         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/app"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
             android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
             android:src="@drawable/newapps" />
        <TextView
             android:id="@+id/soltxt"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/prv_btn"
             android:layout_alignTop="@+id/focusarea"
             android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
             android:text="" />
         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/prv_btn"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image"
             android:layout_alignTop="@+id/nxt_btn"
             android:src="@drawable/previous_normal" />
     </RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Where you get white space?

Comment: in my xml id que_txt is for ques and radio group for answer and id image is for image view of ques here im getting white space..

Comment: please help me what im doing mistake have you saw my screenshot getting white space

Comment: Check flow of execution on if-else condition, what is executes(if/else)?

Comment: change the url in your answer

Answer (score 0):

just remove the ! from your code as like

```
if (pic == null && pic.equals("")) {
```

Comment: Still im getting white space